# Proposal: option to filter out migrated (or closed) questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, closed-questions, filtering

If this already exists, please forgive me. I would like an option to filter out migrated questions and perhaps another for closed questions (from the listing in SO.com/questions).

Currently, I have a page filled with closed/migrated questions on SO, and it's just not practical to leave it all there.

Comment: Even though Bill's answer below explains why you saw this where you did, this feature request still has merit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/can-i-search-for-migrated-questions-or-filter-them-out-in-searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be looking at the [Active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).  I was cleaning up some tags, since it's pretty low traffic right now.  Sorry about that, but it should only take a few more minutes for those questions to clear off the active list (since there won't be any other activity on them to keep them there).  In the meantime, you should be able to just go to the [Newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), which doesn't include those closed questions.

Regardless of my own wild Saturday night activities, this is still a valid feature request.

Comment: Believe me, my Saturday night is not much wilder. Thanks for the explanation though, and kudos on tidying up the place.