# Can I search for migrated questions, or filter them out in searches?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, migration, closed-questions

In the same way that you can search for closed questions using the `closed:1` search clause, is it possible to filter out migrated questions from your search?  I don't see something like a `migrated:0` option, but I'm not as familiar with the search options as I should be.

Why I ask is that it is getting more and more difficult to search for bad closed questions to vote to delete as more questions are migrated, because these migrated questions always appear in the search results for `closed:1`.

I'm aware that outright identifying them as migrated [has been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated), and that a filter for display of migrated questions [has been requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31264/proposal-option-to-filter-out-migrated-or-closed-questions), but I thought that I would check to see if there was a simple search option I was missing.

Comment: I've been going though http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[not-programming-related]%20closed:1&tab=newest the past few days deleting or editing, and could really use this feature.  Perhaps limit the search option to 10k users, as this seems the primary way it is useful?

Comment: I have also been doing this exact thing, and a `migrated:0` option would be extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: added a feature-request tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a `migrated:` option available that behaves like the `closed:` and `wiki:` options do.

Example searches:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=migrated:1
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+migrated:1

This can be used in combinations just like any of the other advanced ninja options.

A few notes:

- Questions that were migrated *then* reopened won't appear here, we treat those as "currently open"
- This required a re-index pass to add the field to our Lucene documents, so it was a 2 stage deploy.  The indexes are now updated (just now re-indexed our network), but the addition of `migrated:` to the `/search` help will happen in the next build.
- This only finds/filters questions migrated *off of* the site you're searching on. [There is no search option for inbound migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215199/migrated-advanced-search-option-should-also-include-questions-migrated-in-not).

Answer (score 1):

I agree, `migrated:0` will be also very useful feature when finding off-topic and not useful questions to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to do a search to find an example to put in a Meta question, and could really have used the `migrated:1` option.