# 'migrated' advanced search option should also include questions migrated in (not just out)

Tags: feature-request, migration, search

Recently I was doing some cleanup of closed posts on the Workplace. Since questions that are migrated in and closed are locked and cannot be touched, I wanted to exclude them. So I made an advanced search to look for `closed:true migrated:false` expecting that would exclude those results.

Only it didn't work. The first result of [this search](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3atrue%20migrated%3afalse) returns [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17863/is-the-pomodoro-technique-useful-in-an-open-plan-office-without-headphones) which is both closed and migrated as evidenced below:

[image: Closed and Migrated]

Thanks to [random having a mind like a steal trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215199/y2-014k-migrated-advanced-search-option-is-broken?noredirect=1#comment694541_215199) he pointed me to where the `migrated:true` option is [explained as only searching for posts that were migrated *out*, not *in*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/can-i-search-for-migrated-questions-or-filter-them-out-in-searches).

Any chance we could get a chance to use the same toggle (or a new toggle) to search for questions migrated in as well?

Comment: Pretty sure `migrated:` is only for away, not inbound and not rejected

Comment: @random, really? That would explain the situation, but boggles the mind as to why. I want to exclude closed migrated here questions from my search as they get auto-locked and can't have anything done to them. Am I just out of luck then?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/can-i-search-for-migrated-questions-or-filter-them-out-in-searches

Comment: @random, well, that answers my question. Really odd behavior along with [is:answer returning questions as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201973/isanswer-flag-in-advanced-search-should-only-return-answers). Sometimes advanced search feels primitive.

Comment: Yes, the migrated search operator is like the duplicate search operator - it's meant to find closed questions which were also migrated away as part of the close process (basically questions which would have a `[migrated]` in the title on your site).

Comment: @animuson, thanks for the heads up. Refrobulated the bug in to a feature-request as the current behavior is allegedly a 'feature' rather than a 'bug'.

Comment: I think having the same search operator return both inbound and outbound migrations would be confusing at best and muddle up search results at worst. Separate operators ("migratedin" and "migratedout", perhaps) would be best, IMO.