# Hide notice for migrated questions after 30 days

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, post-notices, migration-notice

When a question is migrated from another site, a stub is temporarily left on the original site before being automatically deleted after **30 days**. (See *[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/351462)*)

While questions stubs are automatically deleted from the origin site after 30 days, questions that are nearly a ***decade*** old will prominently display their migration status.

[image: Migrated question]
<sub>Migration notice for *[What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/q/149329/358766)*</sub>

I can't think of any reason a 7-8 year old migration notice would be helpful for the average user, or why it should displayed before ***protected*** notices.

<sub>If a user *does* want to see if a question was migrated, they can check a question's [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/149329/revisions), or search [migrated:1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94824/351462).</sub>

Comment: Meh, to me it doesn't feel like it's a critical thing to fix. I honestly don't see a really compelling reason to do it.

Comment: The migration notice is shown because it has historical significance.

Comment: You have a point about the order the notices appear, the migration notice is the least significant post notice. But why remove it? The only reason I can think of is mobile screen real estate, but I don't think that's significant enough to justify developer time.

Comment: @yannis Fair point. Although, at the very least, a protected notice should probably be displayed above a migration notice.

Comment: It could be moved to the edit history, for example. Indeed not critical - few things are - but that's no justification for not considering it.

Comment: "Bumped by Community Users" notices go away within a day or two after they've served their purpose. I believe similar logic could be applied to removing these unnecessary migration notices as well. (+1)

Comment: Note that after the [recent post notices change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide), the migration message (and other post notices) are displayed above the question, rather than below it. This makes it even more "in the way" than it was before, and there's still no real benefit to continuing to show it years after migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality has now been changed as follows

- `MigratedFrom` notices are now hidden after 60 days from migration (you can still see the migration history in the post timeline)
- `MigratedTo` and `MigrationRejection` notices which will continue to be shown as normal

Comment: This [doesn't seem to work properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340151/blank-notification-shown-on-the-top-of-questions-migrated-more-than-60-days-ago) on non-English sites.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Issue has been fixed.