# Drop migration notice after some time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, migration, migration-notice

I have this question on SO:

[How can I generate box-and-whisker plots with variable box width, in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404628/how-can-i-generate-box-and-whisker-plots-with-variable-box-width-in-gnuplot/15404629#15404629)

which I originally asked on CrossValidate, and was migrated. But - that happened 6 years ago, and by now, nobody cares it was migrated: Not CV.SX people, not SO people, and not me.

Now, until a short while ago, the migration notification was smaller, less intrusive and below the message. Now it's more prominent - more contrast from page background, and above the message. (Which is why this is not quite a dupe of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299180/hide-notice-for-migrated-questions-after-30-days)).

Why should anybody be bothered with the migration notice for so long, then?

I suggest a time limit be set for the notice appearing. (I don't care that much about the exact number - let's say, maybe 1 month should be ok.)