# Blank notification shown on the top of questions migrated more than 60 days ago on localized sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, migrated-questions, post-notices, international-sites

When you open the migrated questions from another site, source information (the site name, etc.) it isn't always displayed.

[Bug report on ja.SO meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3143)

- migrated question: [javaで、ここから更に＂00:00にfalseと表示する＂を追加したいのですがどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59271/)
- source site: https://japanese.stackexchange.com
- target site: https://ja.stackoverflow.com

[image]

However, another question that has been migrated in the same way, is displayed normally:

[Docker for Macでimageをpullしたのに/var/lib/dockerディレクトリがない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31973)

---

Update:

Blank notifications remain shown in the post in question after the [notification is changed to be hidden after 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299180/hide-notice-for-migrated-questions-after-30-days).

Comment: would this be an issue with the new post notices, or something un-related?

Comment: Before switching to "new post notices", I think that information has been displayed.

Comment: Update: should be working again. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed. Empty post notices should not happen anymore.

**Update** the regression has been fixed (actually, the original fix did not really fix the issue, the real fix is now in place)

Comment: The same problem has occurred again. - https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200

Comment: Looks like there's been a regression: [bug report here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342089/notification-does-not-appear-in-the-migrated-question)

Comment: What a persistent bug... ;-)

Comment: Well, the first fix didn't actually fix it. It just hid the issue. Then a merge accidentally undid the first fix-not-quite-a-fix. Now it is fixed for real (I hope, otherwise this comment will come back to haunt me).