# Notification does not appear in the migrated question

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, post-notices, regression

In SOja, notification to the questions that have migrated from the main site to the meta is not displayed.
This post is not passed only one day after the migration.
(It does not appear in both "Source" and "Destination".)

Source: [スタックオーバーフローのアカウントを複数の認証サービスに紐付けるには？ [移行済み]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62213)
Destination: [スタックオーバーフローのアカウントを複数の認証サービスに紐付けるには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200)

But, for more than this past migrated question, Notification has been displayed.

[stack overflowの日英アカウントの連携について [移行済み]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61231?noredirect=1)

Comment: This is a regression of [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340151/377214).

Comment: @AdamLear Are non-international sites also affected by this bug in some way?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog In theory, there's nothing different between how we display notices on different sites, although now I see the original bug report was also from SOja. Either way, I pinged Yaakov to take a look as we deployed a change earlier that cleaned out old-style notices out of our code. Sounds like we perhaps missed something in testing/review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is fixed (the proper way this time). Migration notices on all sites should now be showing up properly.