# Proposal : tags for Closed and Migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a closed question be given special tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/can-a-closed-question-be-given-special-tags)

I am suggesting that when a question is closed or migrated the system automatically adds **closed** and **migrated** tags to the question. This will allow us to add them to ignored tags and filter them easily as we need. The two tags must not be usable by users and should be for system use only. This can be useful in all SE sites.

I know a few years ago there was a [post for similar purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31264/proposal-option-to-filter-out-migrated-or-closed-questions) but the answer in the post is not a real answer and he was asking for search mechanism.

Comment: @random Thank you very much the other post is very helpful.